# how to get the link for google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am asked to track the web site hits for my web site. I found out the Google analytics can give me the web site hits. I tried to create the account and listed my web site for web site hits. I can see the web site hits when I open the Google analytics page. Is it possible to send the Google analytics link to my manager so that he can see the web site traffic on his own. If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different ways you can do this.

#### Option 1 - Grant Client Access to GA

If your client has a Google account, you can grant them access to the Google Analytics property. you can give them varying degrees of access depending on what they need. You could even create a report via Explorer and share it with all the people who have access to the property.

#### Option 2 - Create a Looker Report and send link

If your client doesn't want access directly to GA, or there is some concern, then you can create a Looker Studio report that contains all the necessary metrics and data. If your client has a Google account, then you can grant them read only access to this specific report. If they do not have a Google account, then you can change the security settings of the report to be viewable to anyone with the link and send them that.

Both of these options are under the Share menu in the top bar.